# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set error

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

My current code is this and I believe its causing the above error message to appear. I am trying to create a booking page on my website, any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
class Reservation {
  // (A) PROPERTIES
  private $pdo; // PDO object
  private $stmt; // SQL statement
  public $error; // Error message

  // (B) CONSTRUCTOR - CONNECT TO DATABASE
  function __construct() {
    try {
      $this->pdo = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset= utf8".DB_CHARSET,
        DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE =>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
      );
    } catch (Exception $ex) { die($ex->getMessage()); }
  }

  // (C) DESTRUCTOR - CLOSE DATABASE CONNECTION
  function __destruct() {
    $this->pdo = null;
    $this->stmt = null;
  }
```

Comment: `charset= utf8".DB_CHARSET` Wouldn't this evaluate to something like `charset= utf8utf8`?  and `utf8utf8` isn't a valid character set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me, I've already tried ";charset=" . and this still shown the error above. I read online to add the utf8 to see if it works but didn't show a different error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
I tried to connect to mariadb from cakephp.
The problem was that i used the encoding that didnt exist on mariadb server.

cakephp config:

```
    'encoding' => 'utf8mb3'
```

mariadb encodings list:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show character set like 'utf%';
+---------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
| Charset | Description      | Default collation  | Maxlen |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
| utf8    | UTF-8 Unicode    | utf8_general_ci    |      3 |
| utf8mb4 | UTF-8 Unicode    | utf8mb4_general_ci |      4 |
| utf16   | UTF-16 Unicode   | utf16_general_ci   |      4 |
| utf16le | UTF-16LE Unicode | utf16le_general_ci |      4 |
| utf32   | UTF-32 Unicode   | utf32_general_ci   |      4 |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

When i changed cakephp config to:

```
'encoding' => 'utf8'
```

the probles was solved.